# How to make a more efficient "sum-of-divisors" in Racket?

Tags: sum, scheme, racket

```
  (define divides?
    (lambda (a b)
      (= (remainder b a) 0)))

  (define square
    (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

```
(define sum-of-divisors
  (lambda (n)
    (define sum-from-plus ; sum of all divisors of n which are
      (lambda (low addend) ; >= low, plus addend
        (if (and (> low n) (>= (square low) n))
            addend  ;no divisors of n are greater than n
            (sum-from-plus (+ low 1) 
                           (if (divides? low n)
                               (+ addend low)
                               addend)))))
    (sum-from-plus 1 0)))
```

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n)
  (let loop ((i (sub1 (floor (sqrt n)))))
    (cond
      [(= i 0) (- (floor (sqrt n)) 5)]
      [(divides? i (floor (sqrt n)))
       (+ (+ (+ i (floor (sqrt n))) (/ n i)) (loop (sub1 i)))]
      [else (loop (sub1 i)) ])))
```

I need to write a procedure in Racket which finds the sum of the divisors of a certain given number. i.e if n=6, the program should return 12 (1+2+3+6). The former program posted here works, but is too slow, taking about 1500ms when I need it to be about 5% of that. I know the way to make this quicker is to just test the divisors up to the square root of n, but I am unsure how to do this. The ladder code posted is my second attempt at making it quicker, using a 'let loop' to go through the numbers. This code works for a few tests, but takes far too long at higher numbers. What is the best way to do this? Are my methods going in the right direction or should In start over with a new approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the prime factors of *n*, then it is easy and fast to find the divisors of *n*, and their sum. Here is a simple program to find the prime factors of *n*:

```
(define (factors n) ; prime factors of n
  (let ((wheel (vector 1 2 2 4 2 4 2 4 6 2 6)))
    (let loop ((n n) (f 2) (fs (list)) (w 0))
      (if (< n (* f f)) (reverse (cons n fs))
        (if (zero? (modulo n f)) (loop (/ n f) f (cons f fs) w)
          (loop n (+ f (vector-ref wheel w)) fs
                (if (= w 10) 3 (+ w 1))))))))
```

That function uses a prime wheel to compute factors. If your *n* is large, say more than ten or twelve digits, you will want something better. Given the prime factors of *n*, it is easy to find the divisors of *n* by computing the powerset of the prime factors:

```
(define (divisors n) ; divisors of n, including 1 and n
  (let ((divs (list 1)))
    (do ((fs (factors n) (cdr fs))) ((null? fs) (sort < divs))
      (let ((temp (list)))
        (do ((ds divs (cdr ds)))
            ((null? ds) (set! divs (append divs temp)))
          (let ((d (* (car fs) (car ds))))
            (when (not (member d divs))
              (set! temp (cons d temp)))))))))
```

In the study of number theory, the *sigma* function computes the sum of the *x*'th powers of the divisors of *n*. The value of *sigma* can be computed without knowing the divisors if the factorization of *n* is known:

```
(define (sigma x n) ; sum of x'th powers of divisors of n
  (define (add s p m)
    (if (zero? x) (* s (+ m 1))
      (* s (- (expt p (* x (+ m 1))) 1)
         (/ (- (expt p x) 1)))))
  (let ((fs (factors n)))
    (let loop ((prev (car fs)) (mult 1) (sum 1) (fs (cdr fs)))
      (if (null? fs) (add sum prev mult)
        (if (= (car fs) prev)
            (loop prev (+ mult 1) sum (cdr fs))
            (loop (car fs) 1 (add sum prev mult) (cdr fs)))))))
```

Here is a dialog with a Scheme interpreter on your sample problem:

```
> (factors 5040)
(2 2 2 2 3 3 5 7)
> (divisors 5040)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 20 21 24 28 30 35 36 40
 42 45 48 56 60 63 70 72 80 84 90 105 112 120 126 140 144 168
 180 210 240 252 280 315 336 360 420 504 560 630 720 840 1008
 1260 1680 2520 5040)
> (sigma 0 5040)
60
> (sigma 1 5040)
19344
```

When *x* is zero, *sigma* computes the number of divisors. You can run the program at https://ideone.com/GMA6FX. What a fun little diversion for the lunch hour!

Answer (score 0):

Your first program is almost correct already. There are only two small mistakes. You should try out small examples to see how the program evaluates, in order to see where the mistakes are.

> I know the way to make this quicker is to just test the divisors up to the square root of n, but I am unsure how to do this

Currently, the code says: if `(and (> low n) (>= (square low) n))` is true, then it will stop recurring. Otherwise, it will keep continuing.

Say, `n` is 10. You should be able to stop recurring after `low` exceeds sqrt(10). Did that happen? What is the value of `low` that will actually stop the recursion?

Also try when `n` is `9`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed a bit of the code according to what I interpreted of what you said, but it is now giving me wrong answers. I added a new if statement such that when low exceeds (sqrt n) it will stop recurring. 
`(if(> low (sqrt n))
    (+ low addend)`

I also added what I believe the actual value of low to be when it stops recurring to the end, but am unsure of which it is (- low 1) or (square low) ?
`(if (divides? low n)
       (+ addend (square low))
        addend))))))
`
Thanks again for your help, are my edits valid at all?
@Sorawee Porncharoenwase

Answer (score 0):

```
(define divides?
    (lambda (a b)
      (= (remainder b a) 0)))

  (define square
    (lambda (n) (* n n)))

(define sum-of-divisors-eff
  (lambda (n)
    (define sum-from-plus ; sum of all divisors of n which are
      (lambda (low addend) ; >= low, plus addend
        (if (> low (sqrt n))
            addend  ;no divisors of n are greater than n
            (if (= low (sqrt n))
                (+ addend low)
            (sum-from-plus (+ low 1) 
                           (if (divides? low n)
                               (+ addend (+ low (/ n low)))
                               addend))))))
    (sum-from-plus 1 0)))
```

Found the correct answer, takes about 250ms now instead of 2000ms

Answer (score 0):

```
(define sumdiv
  (lambda (n)
    ((lambda (y) (y y n (lambda (s) s)))
     (lambda (s i ret)
       (if (zero? i)
           (ret 0)
           (s s (- i 1)
              (if (zero? (remainder n i))
                  (lambda (x)
                    (ret (+ i x)))
                  ret)))))))
```